# How to Implement Domain Registration API In Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, api, domain

I want to implement domain search facility in my website. As I searched and learn I need to implement Domain search and registration API. As I never did this before and not found much knowledge base documentation on this at beginner level.

Which API I should use SOAP or REST ?

Where do I get API Key for development purpose or Do I need to purchase this?

Please let me know how can I implement or from where should I start at least.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For this we actually need to go for `registrar services reseller` the one i know is `resellerclub`. (Neither advertising nor i'm not related to resellerclub) . I said resellerclub because i had purchased once from them, they provide you pretty much everything, i.e. the fully working and manageable platform. Whey we try to go for API and managing all thing on our own i guess it would take much time with all those backends management stuff for a domain. why don't you try just look at what level of management we require to register and manage domain first. I mean to say there is alot, i guess the best way is to get from reseller serverice provider.